Error when trying to move a folder
When trying to move/copy a folder within the same document library i am getting this error : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The URL "XXX" is not valid. It may refer to a non-existent folder or file, or to a valid folder or file that is not found on the current web."
If i try to move/copy this folder to another document library it works but not the one it's located in.
Thanx in advance for your help

Did you check the length of the full path of the document to move? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#filenamepathlengths

Please check this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/url-invalid-upload-file-to-list#problem
